# Como enviar um objeto usando socket c ++ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, socket

Eu estou tentando enviar um objeto para um server socket. O client e o server têm a mesma classe que eu uso para armazenar os dados. Está tudo funcionando dessa maneira, mas estou tendo problemas no lado do server.

Essa é a classe que estou usando.

```
class tMensagem{

    private:
       string destinatario;
       string mensagem;

    public:
       tMensagem();
       ~tMensagem();

       string getMensagem();
       void setMensagem(string mensagemTMP);
       string getDestinatario();
       void setDestinatario(string destinatarioTMP);
    };
```

Mas quando a string tem mais de 15 caracteres, recebo algum erro para ler no lado do server.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para receber os dados eu estou usando reinterpret_cast

`tMensagem * t2 = reinterpret_cast<tMensagem *>(myMessage);`

E meu recv():

```
recv(ClientSocket, (char *)t2, 1024, 0);
```

Comment: Você não pode fazer simplesmente um "reinterpret_cast" porque as instâncias da classe "string" não são mapeadas diretamente para um array de caracteres. Você vai vai ter que analisar a mensagem recebida, separar os bytes referentes a cada string ("mensagem" e "destinatário"), criar instâncias de "mensagem" "destinatário" como string, e aí então criar uma instância da classe tMensagem.